# Can I sign up in advance for a Joint Security Area tour that departs from Imjingak?

Tags: tours, south-korea, adventure, north-korea

All [Joint Security Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Security_Area) tours (staying on the South Korean side) I have seen depart from Seoul ([example 1](http://www.panmunjomtour.com/), [example 2](http://www.dmztours.com/seoul_dmz_tours.htm), [example 3](http://www.koridoor.co.kr/bbs/board.php?bo_table=travelInfo&wr_id=221)).

Is there any way to sign up in advance for a Joint Security Area tour that departs from Imjingak (which is to my knowledge the closest publicly accessible parking lot)?

Comment: Do you actually know there are tours from Imjingak? When I was there last year all the JSA tours stopped there on the way back but I don't think any tours originated there. I think it's also a stop for non-JSA tours.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf I don't.

Comment: I don't think there is one because of the registration if I recall correctly, DMZ visitors will have check into the tour at the Seoul office so you would have to go there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although it would be convenient for you it is not possible: Imjingak is for concerts / festivals, not for DMZ tour pickups.